# Video pop up autoplay, when pop up does not come up. i can still hear sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I added this pop up to my site, and try add autoplay, but the problem is even the pop dont come up each time you refresh your website, you can still hear the sound.how can i stop the autoplay when pop up doesn't show?

I tried to solve problem by doing this but is still not working

```
<script>
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#popup_87 flex-video iframe").attr("src","https://www.youtube.com/embed/vYAVyEdBfEU?rel=0&autoplay=1;showinfo=0");
});
</script> 



    <!-- START POPUP CODE -->
    <div id="popup_87" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal aria-labelledby="popvideo" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
        <div class="flex-video widescreen"> 
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vYAVyEdBfEU?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" width="640"></iframe>
        </div>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <a href="#" class="clickMe" data-reveal-id="popup_87">popvideo</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

/////

```
<script>
    if (jQuery.cookie('popup{$popup['popup_id']}') === undefined)
    {
        var cookieCount = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var cookieCount = jQuery.cookie('popup{$popup['popup_id']}');
    }
    var popCount = {$popup['popup_max_display_count']};
    if (cookieCount <= popCount) {
        setTimeout(function() {\$(".clickMe").trigger("click");}, 3000);
        cookieCount++;
        jQuery.cookie('popup{$popup['popup_id']}', cookieCount, { expires: {$popup['popup_clear_count_after']} });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if you want to add this to the ajaxComplete event. Any ajax call will call this function which is something you may not want and have random behaviour throughout the page. You will want to trigger functionality based on when you open or close the popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script>
function LoadVideo() {
// If it's visible
    if($("#popup_87").is(":visible"))
    {
        // Load the video and auto play
        $("#popup_87 flex-video iframe").attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/vYAVyEdBfEU?rel=0&autoplay=1;showinfo=0");
    }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT** since more code was added, put the trigger when they click on the link to load the video into the pop-up, otherwise don't load the video in the iframe:

```
<!-- START POPUP CODE -->
<div id="popup_87" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal aria-labelledby="popvideo" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="flex-video widescreen">
    <!-- Removed the source -->
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" width="640"></iframe>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
<div class="hide">
    <a href="#" class="clickMe" data-reveal-id="popup_87">popvideo</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if the following code works, but I just added `LoadVideo` to your script.

```
<script>
    if (jQuery.cookie('popup{$popup['popup_id']}') === undefined)
    {
        var cookieCount = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var cookieCount = jQuery.cookie('popup{$popup['popup_id']}');
    }
    var popCount = {$popup['popup_max_display_count']};
    if (cookieCount <= popCount) {
        LoadVideo();
        setTimeout(function() {\$(".clickMe").trigger("click");}, 3000);
        cookieCount++;
        jQuery.cookie('popup{$popup['popup_id']}', cookieCount, { expires: {$popup['popup_clear_count_after']} });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Blue Eyed I have tried the code, but it still not autoplay.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? It's really hard to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: sorry i am still new to here, thank you so much for helping, this pop up is a widget.

Comment: i tried put the loadvideo there, but is till not working.

Comment: You need to put it in where ever the popup is triggered

Comment: I think the place you added is the place to trigger the pop up.